# getting error in source video using video.js plugin

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am using video.js plugin to control the custom source video and I am getting the following error:

> VIDEOJS: ERROR: (CODE:4 MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED) The media could not be loaded, either because the server or network failed or because the format is not supported.

How can I solve this? Please suggest a solution for me.

Comment: Are you sure the source video format is supported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your support. Finally I solved that issue previously I had

```
<video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered" controls style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height : 100%;">
        <source id="videoMp4" src="" type="video/mp4">
        <source id="videoWebm" src="" type="video/webm">
        <source id="videoOgg" src="" type="video/ogg">
      </video>
```

I removed source tags Now it is working fine instead of this if scr of the source tag is given then it will also work well.